# How and when to use :short in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, int, short

I want to know when to use :`short` in C#?

Please help I want to use it instead of `int`.

Is using `short` a good or bad idea?

Comment: Not a duplicate of the linked question: this question's about C# and that one's about C

Comment: When you understand the differences between both of them, then you will understand when to use one and when other. Same applies to long, uint, ushort, ulong, decimal, double, float and so on....

Comment: if the number that you would like to be used will fit in the given value range. Then you can safely use short. But this applies to all other primitive value types

Comment: Too broad, and can be easily searched for on google, this question should be clsoed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`short` - aka `Int16` - has some very real but limited uses.

Example scenarios:

- when the input value is limited to 16-bits, and you don't want to violate an invariant (perhaps because it maps to a database column that is 16 bits - `smallint` in SQL Server, for example)
- declaring an `enum` that is `: short` for similar reasons
- because you're implementing an algorithm that *demands* 16-bit wrapping behaviour - `CRC-16`, for example
- when you are writing a `struct` with explicit layout that needs to map a very specific configuration (usually related to C/C++ mapping)

It is *unusual*, but by no means unexpected. Similarly: `byte`, `sbyte`, `ushort`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, etc.

`int` is a great *default*, but it is by no means the only option.

Comment: public enum RUNMODE :short
    {
        DebugRun = 1,
        SingleRun = 2,
        ContinuousRun = 3,
        SpecificRun = 4,
        Timer = 5,
        QINQContinuousRun = 6
    }
is this right?

Comment: @Jagath that indeed declares an enum of type `short` (not of type `int`) - if that's what you're asking

Comment: I have used :short instead of int, is this right or will throw any error in future?

Comment: @Jagath "right" is very contextual; there's certainly nothing *wrong* with having enums that are based on `short` - and it can be very desirable *in the right scenarios*. I don't know anything about your scenario, so I can't comment on whether it is "right"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and valuable ideas.
Thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will rarely need to use `short`, and I think it's reasonable to consider its use "bad" unless there's a compelling reason for using it.

`int` will generally perform better than `short` on modern CPUs.

For example, you may need to use `short` in a `struct` used to interoperate with legacy unmanaged code.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's more optimal solution for memory saving to use proper type, because short has 16 bits size and int has 32 bits size.

Comment: It means memory saving too.

Comment: You have to have an truly compelling reason to decide to pick the smallest numeric type in order to minimize memory pressure, In general cases you should stick to the native width type - a 32 bit integer - as these typically  perform better.

Comment: Sure - it must be situation, when application has huge memory demand and utilize almost entire computer's memory. I edited my answer (it's true you should stick to 32 bit integer in general cases).